# SQL, left join, group by, count(*) as haspicture?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by, left-join

Ok so i have some specific query i need to do.

I have a table "description", and i need to find if there is a picture linked to that description, for that, i made a left join, with the table "files".

```
SELECT D.id, COUNT(*) as haspicture
FROM `description`as D 
LEFT JOIN `files` as F ON D.id=F.id  
GROUP BY D.id
```

It works well, but the column haspicture contain what it should contain, the number of files found.
I just want to set haspicture to 1 if there is at least 1 file attached.

I need it to be at 1, because then i have ways of sorting the results with differents levels of priorities. Of course, i've shorten the real query, i select more than D.id, and haspicture in reality.

Comment: I added the mysql tag because of the backticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `case` statement.  Also, because careful what you are counting:

```
SELECT D.id,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(f.id) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as haspicture
FROM `description`D LEFT JOIN
     `files` F
      ON D.id = F.id  
GROUP BY D.id;
```

You might find that the following performs better, because there is no larger `group by`:

```
select d.id,
       (exists (select 1 from files where d.id = f.id)) as haspicture
from description d;
```

An index on `files(id)` is needed for optimal performance.

Comment: great, both solutions work, but I didn't knew or thought about the second one, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT IF(COUNT('*') > 0, 1, 0)) as haspicture`

Answer (score 0):

Using the count, but specifying f.id (if you just do COUNT(*) then it will always be at least 1, as it will count a description where there are no files as one row):-

```
SELECT D.id, if(COUNT(f.id) = 0, 0, 1) AS haspicture
FROM `description`as D 
LEFT JOIN `files` as F ON D.id=F.id  
GROUP BY D.id
```

Or using a correlated sub query (not keen on these):-

```
SELECT D.id, IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM files WHERE files.ID = D.id) > 0, 1, 0) AS haspicture
FROM `description`as D
```